# Google Drive DriEdit example not working with my FULL_AUTH_URL

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I have set a setup of Google Drive sample DriEdit code in my wesite. It is authenticating user file but once authentication done it take back user to the redirect url, but when i am using  default `FULL_AUTH_URL` url it working file, but in my case it is not working here is my URl.

```
const FULL_AUTH_URL='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace:

- **MY_CLIENT_ID** by the Client ID of your application which you can find in the Google APIs Console for the project that you have created. See https://developers.google.com/drive/register
- **redirect_uri** bu the URL where the user gets redirect to after he approves the OAuth flow. Usually the main page of your website or a different OAuth handler. This is usually all described in the Dr Edit sample documentation. Make sure you read this: https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/python

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create a *"Client ID for web applications"* - maybe a service account works, too (web services might be easier to connect, because for service accounts one need to install a certificate file and send it on auth).

Once oAuth is setup properly, you should at least get any error message from Google.

Just don't use the Drive API credentials, they have no function yet.

Hope this get's you started.